# Apply SOLID Principle to basic app

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, solid-principles

Hi i am trying to apply the SOLID Principle to my code until i came across the interface and Dependency Inversion.

i am just having trouble with the constructor of FlightValidator class.
please can do advice?enter code here

```
you can get the full project here: https://www.sendspace.com/file/zk022f
```

i am confused on this class. in how do i create an instance of it?

```
public class FlightValidator
{
    private IValidator _validator;
    private GeneralFlightValidation _generalFlightValidation;
    private BasicFlightValidation _basicFlightValidation;
    private int flightRuleType;

    public FlightValidator(IValidator _validator,
                            int flightRuleType
                            )
    {
        this._validator = _validator;
        this.flightRuleType = flightRuleType;
    }

    public void GetFlightRule(ScheduledFlight scheduledFlight)
    {

        switch(this.flightRuleType)
        {
            case (short)FlightRuleType.STANDARD:
                {
                    this._validator.FlightValidator(scheduledFlight);
                    break;
                }
            case (short)FlightRuleType.BASIC:
                {
                    this._validator.FlightValidator(scheduledFlight);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    this._validator.FlightValidator(scheduledFlight);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}

public enum FlightRuleType : int
{
    STANDARD,
    BASIC
}
```

Comment: First off.. Why do you even have that switch statement? Isn't it equal to `_validator.FlightValidator(scheduledFlight);` ?

Comment: i am trying to give the user a choice in the rules they want to chose

Comment: i was having issues passing it to _generalFlightValidation and _generalFlightValidation, which i am still on.

Answer (score 2):

> i am confused on this class. in how do i create an instance of it?

You can just pass the dependency to the constructor:

```
IValidator validator = ...    
FlightValidator flightValidator = new FlightValidator(validator);
```

or, if you're using an IoC container (e.g. Unity):

```
FlightValidator flightValidator = container.Resolve<FlightValidator>();
```

Anyway, I find your code a bit confusing. Your `FlightValidator` class depends on an `IValidator`, which itself has a `FlightValidator` method (very bad name for a method by the way)... So what is the `FlightValidator` class good for, if it just calls another thing that does the flight validation?

Comment: i forgot to change the method name.

OK you said about the IValidator validator = ...> what class?

Comment: What bothers me is that your `FlightValidator` class doesn't seem to actually validate a flight. And the name of the `GetFlightRule` method implies that it should return something (a flight rule), but its return type is void. What is the `FlightValidator` class *supposed* to do?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at here is **[Dependency Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921152.aspx)**. The general idea is to remove the dependency from the class and **injecting** said dependency via the constructor. This allows your class to have less responsibilities, promotes re-use, which results in a more *agile* solution.

To instantiate this class, you can use *poor man's* dependency injection, like this:

```
IValidator myValidator = new SomeValidator();
FlightValidator flightValidator = new FlightValidator(myValidator, 69);
```

For a more elegant approach, you can use **[Inversion of Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx)**.